# What does "Invalid token" indicate in this TMSL script?

Tags: ssms, ssas-tabular

I'm attempting to migrate an existing SSAS database to a new server. From SSMS, I right click the database and choose **Script > Script Database as > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window**

[image]

Then I go to the new server and try to run the script. I'm getting odd parsing errors for Power Query expressions in the model. The current error is:

```
Query (339, 113) The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 339, Offset 113, ?.
```

And here is the offending part of the script:
[image]

Any ideas? I've tried escaping the question marks and <> with backslashes to no avail. I get an invalid token on the backslash at the same position.

**UPDATE**: I think that something with SSMS is wrong. I've been able to use the TMSL script with pbi-tools and it works fine. I've had similar problems with TMSL scripts in SSMS for a while now across many versions of SSMS. Any idea how to open a ticket with Microsoft on this?